# prestashop - Can't load Order status at line 242 in file classes/PaymentModule.php

Tags: prestashop, e-commerce

when I order with an obligation to pay

[PrestaShopException]
Can't load Order status
at line 242 in file classes/PaymentModule.php

```
237.         }
238. 
239.         $order_status = new OrderState((int) $id_order_state, (int) $this->context->language->id);
240.         if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($order_status)) {
241.             PrestaShopLogger::addLog('PaymentModule::validateOrder - Order Status cannot be loaded', 3, null, 'Cart', (int) $id_cart, true);
242.             throw new PrestaShopException('Can\'t load Order status');
243.         }
244. 
245.         if (!$this->active) {
246.             PrestaShopLogger::addLog('PaymentModule::validateOrder - Module is not active', 3, null, 'Cart', (int) $id_cart, true);
247.             die(Tools::displayError());
PaymentModuleCore->validateOrder - [line 58 - modules/ps_wirepayment/controllers/front/validation.php] - [9 Arguments]
Ps_WirepaymentValidationModuleFrontController->postProcess - [line 270 - classes/controller/Controller.php]
ControllerCore->run - [line 509 - classes/Dispatcher.php]
DispatcherCore->dispatch - [line 24 - override/classes/Dispatcher.php]
Dispatcher->dispatch - [line 28 - index.php]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert with phpmyadmin the table

ps_order_state:

```
  INSERT INTO `ps_order_state` (`id_order_state`, `invoice`, `send_email`, `module_name`, `color`, `unremovable`, `hidden`, `logable`, `delivery`, `shipped`, `paid`, `deleted`) VALUES
(1, 0, 1, 'cheque', 'RoyalBlue', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(2, 1, 1, '', 'LimeGreen', 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
(3, 1, 1, '', 'DarkOrange', 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
(4, 1, 1, '', 'BlueViolet', 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0),
(5, 1, 0, '', '#108510', 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0),
(6, 0, 1, '', 'Crimson', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(7, 1, 1, '', '#ec2e15', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(8, 0, 1, '', '#8f0621', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(9, 1, 1, '', 'HotPink', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
(10, 0, 1, 'bankwire', 'RoyalBlue', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(11, 0, 0, '', 'RoyalBlue', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(12, 1, 1, '', 'LimeGreen', 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
(13, 1, 0, '', '#DDEEFF', 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ps_wirepayment module is trying to set an order status to an invalid / deleted **id_order_state**.
If you haven't modified it , bankwire modulee relies on ps_configuration "**PS_OS_BANKWIRE**" status value,
so make sure the ID value is valid and links to a valid order state in your database.